# IDP Availablity for SAML

Tags: saml

I am implementing Single Sign On through SAML. For this, I need an IDP (Identity Provider) which can be installed on-premise. Can you provide me the list of IDP's available and their licence Cost and supported platform? I searched and found like Gluu, Shibboleth but not finding the exact. Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [SAML-based products and services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML-based_products_and_services).

I have used shibboleth and simpleSAMLphp - both open source - both work.

If you want to pay, then Ping Federate, ADFS, OpenAM and Auth0 are all good options.

Comment: Can we install Shibboleth on my network? Is there any free trial or one time installation?

Comment: Do i need to buy some licenese to install Shibboleth or it is completely free to install? Please suggest.

Comment: AFAIK - open source - free to download and install.

Comment: @ShilpiAgarwal It's completely free and open source. You can use windows installer if you need it in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to share our user identity with anyone else. We are using Progress Open Edge Database to store user id and password and authenticate from there. 
Is there any way that we install IDP on-premise where our user identities should not be shared in cloud rather it is in our network? 
I am using OneLogin but it allows to share user id with themseleves but i do not want to share user id with any IDP, instead it should be on my network, that is why i am lokking for an IDP which can be installed on-premise.

Answer (score 0):

A little old post but maybe someone else looking for an answer can benefit. There are many Identity Providers available out there. It depends on your use case which one you should go with and if you need an open source or if you want full support for it.

If your use case requires you to support all the IAM features with easy to configure UI then Keycloak and miniOrange are the ones I would recommend. Keycloak is open source and miniOrange charges for support if you need it. There are others like Shibboleth and SimpleSAMLphp but they don't have an intuitive and easy to use UI and you will have make changes in their config files directly.

As you already pointed above since you don't have any cost issues then you can check out ADFS and Ping Federate.

Answer (score 0):

My best choices will be:

- Paid : PingIdentity
- Free (as in community) : WSO2 IS, Forgerock OpenAM, Redhat Keycloak
- Free : SAMLphp, ADFS (you paid for the servers anyway)